# In how many ways can a set of integers be summed to a target integer?

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set $X$ of $m$ distinct positive integers $X = \{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m\}$ and a positive integer $N$, in how many ways can $N$ be expressed as a sum $N = \sum_i y_i$ with $y_i\in X$? The order of the sum does not matter.

Comment: Seems like more information on the $x_i$ would be needed. Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: That is a partition of $N$, with parts belonging to the set $X$, and in general does not have a close form.

Comment: You might be interested in the "subset sum problem". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Answer (score 0):

Without further information on the nature of the $x_i$, I can only offer $$\sum_{S\subseteq X}\large\delta_{(\sum_S s_i)(N)}$$ where $\delta_{ij}$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta). Basically though this is just re-stating the problem.

There might be more scope for useful description for special forms like $X=\{1,2,3,\ldots,m\}$ but even then because the number of elements in the subset is variable, there's no clean transformation to another partition.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive definition of a function which returns the
number of those partitions might look like this:
$$
\begin{align}
f(N, X) &= 0 \quad (N \le 0) \\
f(N, \emptyset) &= 0 \\
f(N, \{ x \} \cup X) &= \delta[N–x] + f(N-x, X) + f(N, X)
\end{align}
$$
where I used the Dirac delta in discrete / DSP notation:
$$
\delta[n] =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } n=0 \\
0 & \text{if } n\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}
\end{cases}
$$
Update: I assumed the elements of $X$ being used only once in the sum.

Comment: Note that a member $x\in X$ can appear *multiple* times in the sum. But writing a recursion is seems like a good idea. The choice can be whether $x$ is chosen at least once, or not. This leads to: $f(N, X\cup \{x\}) = f(N - x, X\cup \{x\}) + f(N, X)$

Comment: Also you can define $f(0, X) = 1$ instead of 0. Since the empty set is a subset of $X$.

Comment: Maybe the recursion can be solved for special cases of $X$?

Comment: I have to rethink the problem for multiple use in the sum.